# Surjective ring maps always induce isomorphic residue field?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Context. I am trying to understand why [10.115.4 follows from 10.115.3](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07NB). I believe it boils down to the following.

> Let $(S',m') \rightarrow (S,m)$ be a surjection of finite type local $k$ algebras. Then we have induced isomoprhism of residue fields
> $$ \kappa(m') \rightarrow \kappa(m) $$

But this seems to be true more general: that we do note need the condition of finite type local $k$ algebras. I believe that

> If $S' \rightarrow S$ is a surjective ring map, then for all prime $p$ of $S$ with preimage $p'$, we have induced isomorphism of residue fields.
> $$ \kappa(p')\rightarrow \kappa(p)$$

The argument is simply because the induced map is surjective, and any field homomorphism is either $0$ or injective.

Am I correct?

Comment: If you quotient out by a prime you get an integral domain, not a field. But otherwise, yes.

Comment: unrelated to the mathematics, but I find it amusing how close our names are

Comment: @ZhenLin wait where do I get an integral domain?

Comment: By definition of residule i mean $\kappa(p):= S_p/pS_p$, where $S_p$ denotes the localization of $S$ at prime $p$.

Comment: I was speaking of $S / p$ rather than $S_p / p S_p$. Anyway, $S_p / p S_p$ is isomorphic to the fraction field of $S / p$, and since the induced homomorphism $S' / p' \to S / p$ is an isomorphism, so too are the fraction fields.

Comment: $S=S'/I'$ and $p=p'/I'$. Then $S/p=S'/p'$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct when you claim that the following is true.

**Proposition:** Let $S'\to S$ be a surjective ring homomorphism, let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $S,$ and let $\mathfrak{p}'$ be its preimage in $S'.$ Then the induced map $\kappa(\mathfrak{p}')\to\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$ is an isomorphism.

And you are also correct that the implication 10.115.3$\implies$10.115.4 boils down to this claim, as 10.115.3 implies that
\begin{align*}
\dim_{x'}X' - \dim_x X &= (\dim(S'_{\mathfrak{p}'}) + \operatorname{trdeg}_k(\kappa(\mathfrak{p}'))) - (\dim(S_{\mathfrak{p}}) + \operatorname{trdeg}_k(\kappa(\mathfrak{p})))\\
&= \operatorname{height}(\mathfrak{p}') - \operatorname{height}(\mathfrak{p}) + \operatorname{trdeg}_k(\kappa(\mathfrak{p}')) - \operatorname{trdeg}_k(\kappa(\mathfrak{p})),
\end{align*}
so that all you need to prove is that $\kappa(\mathfrak{p}')\to\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$ is an isomorphism.

However, the requirement that $S'$ and $S$ are finite type $k$-algebras is hidden in the proof of 10.115.3. To prove 10.115.3, they invoke [10.113.5](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00OT), which in turn relies on [10.113.4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00OS):

**Lemma 10.113.4:** Let $k$ be a field. Let $S$ be a finite type $k$-algebra which is an integral domain. Then $\dim(S)=\dim(S_\mathfrak{m})$ for any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $S$. In words: every maximal chain of primes has length equal to the dimension of $S$.

The proof of this lemma requires us to write $S\cong k[x_1,\dots, x_n]/\mathfrak{p}.$ While I do not have a counterexample to the statement of lemma 10.113.4 if we drop the assumption that $S$ is finite type at the moment, I would imagine that odd things can happen and this could fail.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explaination!  Hope you can have a look at my latest post. : P