# Why do the matrix entries $a_{ij}$ of the presentation of the $A$-module $M$ lies in the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules

I am looking at the proof the following statement:

**Statement:** Let $(A, \kappa, \mathfrak{m})$ be a Noetherian local ring with $p=0$ in $A$, where $\mathfrak{m}$ is the unique maximal ideal and $\kappa$ is the residue field. Let $F:A \to A$ be the Frobenius map defined by $F(a)=a^p$. If $M$ is finitely generated $A$-module such that $M \otimes_{F,A} A \cong M$, then $M$ is free $A$-module.

The result is from here [the Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0EBU).

> **Proof.**
> Choose a presentation $A^m→A^n→M$ which induces an isomorphism $\kappa^n→M/\mathfrak{m}M$. Let $T=(a_{ij})$ be the matrix of the map $A^m→A^n$. Observe that $a_{ij} \in \mathfrak{m}$. Applying base change by $F$, using right exactness of base change, we get a presentation $A^m→A^n→M$ where the matrix is $T=(a_{ij}^p)$. Thus we have a presentation with $a_{ij} \in \mathfrak{m}^p$. Repeating this construction we find that for each $e≥1$ there exists a presentation with $a_{ij} \in \mathfrak{m}^e$. This implies the fitting ideals (More on Algebra, Definition [$15.8.3$](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07Z9)) $\text{Fit}_k(M)$ for $k<n$ are contained in $\bigcap_{e \geq 1} \mathfrak{m}^e$. Since this is zero by Krull's intersection theorem (Algebra, Lemma [$10.51.4$](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00IP)) we conclude that $M $is free of rank $n$ by More on Algebra, Lemma [$15.8.7$](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07ZD).

---

I can not understand the highlighted lines.

- Why the matrix entries $a_{ij} \in \mathfrak{m}$ ?
- every time applying base change by the Frobenius $F$, the matrix of the presentation of $M$ will be $(a_{ij}),~(a_{ij}^p),~(a_{ij}^{p^2}), \cdots$, and so $a_{ij} \in \mathfrak{m}^{p^l}$ for some positive integer $l$. Clearly we can not apply "fundamental theorem of arithmetic". So why did the proof claimed that "for each integer $e \geq 1$ there is a presentation of $M$ such that $a_{ij} \in \mathfrak{m}^e$ ? I don't see how it is true.
- In the whole proof, I didn't really realised at what point the assumption $M \otimes_{F,A} A \cong M$ has been used ? Was it required only to get compatibility of Frobenius map when doing base change ? For, we had the original presentation of $M$:
  \begin{align} &A^m \overset{\varphi}{\longrightarrow} A^n \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow 0\\& A^m \overset{F_A(\varphi)}{\longrightarrow} A^n \longrightarrow M \otimes_{A,F} A \longrightarrow 0~~\text{applying base change by Frobenius $F$} \\ &A^m \overset{F_A(\varphi)}{\longrightarrow} A^n \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow 0 ~~\text{since $M \otimes_{A,F}A \cong M$} \end{align}
  I think this was the reason for the assumption $M \otimes_{A,F} A \cong M$. Here matrix of $\varphi$ is $(a_{ij})$ and matrix of $F_A(\varphi)$ is $(a_{ij}^p)$.

I appreciate your explanations.

Comment: This question could be improved in a few ways: "Proof of a theorem from Stack project, algebraic geometry /commutative algebra" is a very uninformative title. Do you know how many theorems are in the Stacks Project? Lots! Most of them deal with algebraic geometry and/or commutative algebra. Next, you have a number of typos here - for one, you say characteristic zero at the start when this is clearly a characteristic $p$ result. Finally, [images of text are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged).

Comment: @KReiser, thank you for your suggestion. I have revised the question. I always appreciate suggestions to improve a question rather than downvote. Just one thing. I think this result is valid for characteristic zero local ring as well if we extend the Frobenius. It is mentioned that "$A$ is Noetherian local where $p=0$".  What do you say ?

Comment: The Frobenius is not a ring homomorphism unless we are in characteristic $p$. It makes no sense to consider any of this in characteristic zero. If you read the source, the assumption is "$p=0$ in $A$", which is exactly the statement that $A$ has characteristic $p$.

Comment: @KReiser, sorry. I meant that probably in ring of witt vectors there has been generalisation of frobenius morphism. I have seen it somewhere. Do you know any such generalisation ?

Comment: Yes, there's all sorts of fun to be had with the Witt vectors, but none of that is directly relevant to this question because here $p=0$ but over in the Witt vectors $p\neq 0$ (in fact, that's kind of the whole *point* of the Witt vectors).

Comment: @KReiser, thanks. Why the does authors of Stacks project say $p=0$ instead of saying ring of characteristic $p$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Why the matrix entries $a_{ij} \in \mathfrak{m}$ ?

Because the presentation "induces an isomorphism" mod $\mathfrak m$. That is $A^m\otimes A/\mathfrak m\rightarrow A^n\otimes A/\mathfrak m\simeq M\otimes A/\mathfrak m$, hence $A^m\otimes A/\mathfrak m \rightarrow A^n\otimes A/\mathfrak m$ must be the $0$ homomorphism, in other words $A^m$ was sent to $\mathfrak m A^n$. Perhaps it needs to be proved that such a presentation exists.

We give a completely self-contained proof of the whole thing. Let $\{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n\}$ be a minimal generating set of $M$. Consider the surjective map $\rho:A^n\rightarrow M, \rho(e_i)=a_i$. We claim $\ker\rho$ is contained in $\mathfrak mA^n$. Indeed if $\rho((c_i)_{i=1}^n)=\sum_{i=1}^nc_ia_i=0$, then if $c_j\not\in\mathfrak m$, $c_j$ would be invertible, hence $a_j=\sum_{i\not=j}c_j^{-1}c_ia_i$, so $a_j$ is not needed in the generating set. Now pick a generating set of $\ker\rho$ (which exists because $A$ is noetherian), then the matrix that send $A^m$ to $\ker\rho$ must be full of elements $a_{ij}\in\mathfrak m$.

- So why did the proof claimed that "for each integer $e \geq 1$ there is a presentation of $M$ such that $a_{ij} \in \mathfrak{m}^e$ ?

That's a typo. It sould be $a_{ij}\in\mathfrak m^{p^l}$ as you claimed, and it won't affect the rest of the argument, since $\cap_{e\ge1}\mathfrak m^e=\cap_{l\ge1}\mathfrak m^{p^l}$.

You are also right about the last point.

Comment: Excellent. Just few things. In 4th line, the minimal set of generators of what ? You mean generators of $M$, i think. Finally, to clear my understanding, why is $M \otimes A/\mathfrak{m}=0$ ? Is the reason that $A/\mathfrak{m}$ acts as zero on $M$ ?

Comment: Sorry that I should not claim $A^m\otimes A/\mathfrak m=0$, but the image of $A^m$ must be send to $0$ after tensoring with $A/\mathfrak m$, or equivalently $A^m$ is sent to $\mathfrak m A^n$. Now corrected.

Comment: the presentation of finitely generated always induces such ismorphism because $A^n \to M$ is surjective by definition. The answer is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3780376/surjective-ring-maps-always-induce-isomorphic-residue-field?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I want to understand the basic calculation why $A^m \to \mathfrak{m} A^n$ do imply $a_{ij} \in \mathfrak{m}$. See the next comment.....

Comment: Since $A^n$ and $A^m$ are finitely generated, $A^m=\text{span} \{x_1,\cdots, x_m\}$ and $A^n=\text{span}\{y_1, \cdots, y_n \}$.  So for $f: A^m \to A^n$, $f(x_i)=a_{i1}y_1+\cdots+a_{in}y_n,~ 1 \leq i \leq n.$ But since $A^m /\mathfrak{m} \to A^n/\mathfrak{m}$ is zero map, we have $$(a_{i1}+\mathfrak{m})(y_1+\mathfrak{m}A^n)+\cdots+(a_{in}+\mathfrak{m})(y_n+\mathfrak{m}A^n)=0+\mathfrak{m}A^n$$ which implies $a_{i1}+\mathfrak{m}=\cdots=a_{in}+\mathfrak{m}=0+\mathfrak{m}$. That is $a_{ij} \in \mathfrak{m}$. Am I right ?

Comment: @MAS The link you give only applies to ring homo, not modules. Take any field $A=\kappa$, that is $\mathfrak m=0$, it's clear that not every linear surjective map is an isom. Your last comment is correct. I have updated my answer to give essentially the same proof.

Comment: I have a comment. The Theorem above claims $M$ is free while the [reference](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07ZD), they have used is for "locally free" module. Can you please check the last line of the proof of the theorem above ?

Comment: I don't know if this is the quickest way to reach the conclusion, but finite locally free modules are projective and projective modules over local rings are free.

Comment: yes. But the if you see the last line of [proof](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07ZD), they proved $M$ is free while the statement just asked only finite locally free not free. So they proved more than requirement. Is it ?